# mysql-Calpont not starting

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-error-1064, infinidb

I have mysql-Calpont installed in a Linux machine. When i try to start mysql-Calpont, it gives an error: **Starting MySQL. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.**

Totally new to Linux. Need help to figure out why this is happening and how to get mysql started.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the last lines of the mysql log which will contain the error

Comment: @Antonis -- The log-bin was commented out from the my.cnf file, so I guess there was not log created. I enabled this tag and entered the name and path of the log file.. but it did not create any log file... Am I doing the right thing to create a log or looking at the wrong log file?

Comment: not bin-log (which is binary log) i mean the log-error variable

Comment: This is what the log says:  **140717 10:49:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/Calpont/mysql/db
140717 10:49:18 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user exists!

140717 10:49:18 [ERROR] Aborting

140717 10:49:18 [Note] /usr/local/Calpont/mysql/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140717 10:49:18 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/Calpont/mysql/db/optimus.pid ended**

Comment: Execute as root:  groupadd mysql
useradd -r -g mysql mysql

Comment: Then retry to start mysql

Answer (score 0):

Seems like mysql user is missing. Please execute as root: 

groupadd mysql 

useradd -r -g mysql mysql